# Wrong DAY_OF_WEEK

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek

Hy, I wrote the code below and I don't understand why it's not working. For example for today (04.04.2020) `dayOfWeek` should be 7, but the result is 2….

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2020, 4, 4);
    int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek); //this print 2 on the console
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line of code:

```
calendar.set(2020, 4, 4);
```

It starts with January with the number 0. So the correct code would be:

```
calendar.set(2020, 3, 4);
```

Full code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2020, 3, 4);
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

Outputs:

```
7
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand how it works!

Comment: If you wanted to use the `Calendar` class (which we generally don’t), you should specify April using the named constant `Calendar.APRIL`, not the meaningless `3`.

Comment: I'm new in Java, I had an exercises as homework, was specified to use Calendar class, and I had as inputs numbers for moths and days. Thanks for the specifications, i will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Ailema Thank you for the background. I find it awfully unfortunate that there are still teachers requiring students to use this and other classes that were replaced by far superior ones 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

While @Kaimson's answer is correct, I would opt for [using java8s LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of java.util.Calendar, where you're code will be:

```
DayOfWeek.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()).name()
```

If you're not using java8, look into [joda time](https://joda.org), which has a similar API:

```
DateTime.now().dayOfWeek() // yields a number 1-7 representing the current day
```

Comment: Yeah, I've found a solution with LocalData class, but I wanted to understand why my first solution was not good.

Comment: It's not good because the Calendar/Date library has many, many shortcomes, as adumbrated on the joda website.

Comment: If using Java 6 or 7 and open to an external dependency, I’d clearly recommend [the backport of java.time](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) over [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), though both are good options.